# Deleting items in a specified index range for linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

In my linked list, I wrote a function drop_between which deletes nodes in a specified range.

everything other than drop_between function works fine.

My expected output:

```
sample = Deque()
sample.push_front(3)
sample.push_front(2)
sample.push_front(1)
sample.push_front(0)
linked list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
sample.drop_between(1,3)
linked list = [0, 3] # 1, 2 removed
```

However, my function removes everything that is specified in the drop_between except the very first number that is passed in (which is the start).

My linked list function file:

```
class Node:
    """
    Initialize empty node
    """

    def __init__(self, data, prev = None, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
        self.prev = prev

class Deque:
    """
    A double-ended queue
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes an empty Deque
        """
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Computes the number of elements in the Deque
        :return: The size of the Deque
        """
        return self.size

    def push_front(self, e): 
        """
        Inserts an element at the front of the Deque
        :param e: An element to insert
        """
        new_head = Node(data = e, next = self.head)

        if len(self) == 0:
            self.tail = new_head

        if self.head:
            self.head.prev = new_head
        self.head = new_head
        self.size += 1

    def drop_between(self, start, end): #need help with this function
        """
        Deletes elements from the Deque that within the range [start, end)
        :param start: indicates the first position of the range
        :param end: indicates the last position of the range(does not drop this element)
        """
        cur_index = 0
        if (start > end):
            raise IndexError
        if (start < 0):
            raise IndexError
        curr = self.head

        while curr.next:
            last_node = curr
            curr = curr.next
            if ((cur_index >= start) and (cur_index < end)):
                print("here", cur_index)
                last_node.next = curr.next.next
                curr.next.next.prev = last_node.next
            cur_index += 1

    def listprint(self, node):
        """
        Prints each element of the node front to back
        :param node:
        """
        while (node is not None):
            print(node.data)
            last = node
            node = node.next
```

My main file:

```
def main():
    D = Deque()
    D.push_front(9)
    D.push_front(8)
    D.push_front(7)
    D.push_front(6)
    D.push_front(5)
    D.push_front(4)
    D.push_front(3)
    D.push_front(2)
    D.push_front(1)
    D.push_front(0)

    D.drop_between(4,7)

    D.listprint(D.head)
```

The output of my main displays the numbers 0-4 and 7-9 inclusive, but the output of 4 was unexpected. How am I able to properly unlink the 4 in my linked list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, note that `collections` already have a [implementation of deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

With that in mind, your task ends up really simple:

```
from collections import deque

def drop_between(d, start, end):
    d.rotate(-start)
    for __ in range(end-start):
        d.popleft()
    d.rotate(+start)


d = deque(n for n in range(20))

print(d)
drop_between(d, 5, 9)
print(d)
```

However, if you are not allowed to use this external source, I advise to code a similar logic.

Comment: Is d "self"? When I try  self.rotate(-start), I am getting an error that .rotate is not a function of the class? I am trying to use rotate as a function

Comment: If you implement rotate in your `Deque` class, then you could use it as `Deque.rotate(self, ...)`. But, in my example, rotate is a function of the `deque` class from `collections`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your **drop_between** function with this:

```
def drop_between(self, start, end): #need help with this function
    """
    Deletes elements from the Deque that within the range [start, end)
    :param start: indicates the first position of the range
    :param end: indicates the last position of the range(does not drop this element)
    """
    cur_index = 0
    if (start > end):
        raise IndexError
    if (start < 0):
        raise IndexError

    #assumption: start node != head
    prev_to_start_node = self.get_node_by_index(start-1)
    end_node = self.get_node_by_index(end)
    prev_to_start_node.next = end_node
    end_node.prev = prev_to_start_node

def get_node_by_index(self,index):
    i = 0
    curr = self.head
    while i < index and curr.next:
        curr = curr.next
        i+=1
    return curr
```

Notice that I added **get_node_by_index**, so if you wish to remove it, you'll need to replace the code accordingly.